# Log for affected rows of select and insert command - SQL Server- Help needed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-job

so I have some commands which I want to put in a stored procedure(then stored procedure executed by a job) to automate. What I need is to make some sort of log(file or table?!) where to have the affected rows a **select** or **insert** did and also how long they took to execute. So can you help me with some ideas? thanks

### Examples below:

```
truncate table table_xyz

insert into table_aaa

select * from (select * from table_dsd union all select * from table_dsdf)
```

### ex: "40234 rows affected" ; 00:00:35

some selects

Answer (score 1):

one simple way would be to do like this

```
declare @startdate datetime=getdate()

select * from sometbl

--log data
select @@rowcount,datediff(minute,@startdate,getdate())
```